# Какой метод DevOps выбрать для удобной разработки и тестирования?

Tags: php, gitlab, git-branch, devops, git-flow

На текущей момент с командой разработки бекенда пользуемся следующим подходом:

Есть тестовая ветка `staging`, из которой мы создаем ветки (`feature-ветки`) для наших задач. После выполнения мерджим задачу обратно в `staging` и через GitLab проект разворачивается на тестовом сайте для тестирования нашим тестировщиком. Если все задачи успешно прошли тесты - мерджим тестовую ветку `staging` в прод ветки (у нас несколько стран, потому прод. веток много, например `master_kz`, `master_pl` и тд.)

Но мы уперлись в одну проблему. Некоторые задачи не проходят тесты и их нужно доработать. Тогда на ветке `staging` находятся часть готовых к релизу задач, а часть неготовых. И тогда либо приходится ждать пока разработчики исправят забагованные заачи, либо мерджить как есть, откатывая недоработанные задачи. Это очень неудобно и создает путаницу.

Пробовал читать разные подходы по типу Git-flow, GitHub-flow, GitLab-flow, но я не понимаю как они решают эту проблему. Прошу помочь разобраться и выбрать оптимальный подход под наш случай.

Comment: 1) Это **не** девопсовая проблема и задача (не техническая, а организационная - процесс построен криво) 2) Для упрощения жизни крайне желательно использовать *конвенциональную лексику*, которую понимают все, одинаково, а не только у вас в вашем огороженном загончике - текст "заливаем задачу обратно" я, к примеру в git-операции перевожу с трудом (нет однозначности)

Comment: Я не знаю как правильно назвать данный вопрос. Подскажите как правильно

Comment: Не очень понятна проблема. Если хотите иметь возможность отправлять в прод результаты выполненных задач независимо друг от друга, то и тестировать их надо независимо [one at a time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4IRKZNphk0).

Comment: Проблема в выборочном мердже задач, которые прошли тестирования. Как не заливать те, которые ещё на доработке?